# How can I get more than one piece of salvage from enemy mechs?

Tags: battletech

When I blow up an enemy mech I mostly get one piece of salvage, but sometimes I get two or three! What is causing the difference, and can I control it so I can get working mechs faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable a mech by "coring" it (shooting out the center torso), you get 1 part.

If you disable the mech by "legging" it (shooting out both legs), you get 2 parts.

If you disable the mech by removing the pilot (either shooting out the head, or causing enough pilot injuries to kill the pilot), you get 3 parts.